# Where does the function $f(z)=z\bar z+z/\bar z$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Tags: complex-analysis

Where does the function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}, f(z)=z\bar z+z/\bar z$ (where $\bar z$ is the complex conjugate of $z$) satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations?

I tried to write $f(z)$ as: $$f(z)=x^2+y^2+(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)+(2xyi)/(x^2+y^2)$$ but if I work out the jacobian, it's not of the vorm $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ (Cauchy Riemann equations). Can somebody help me out?

Comment: You can write ${\overline z}$ using "{\overline z}" (which is what everone else calls the complex conjugate).  Some people would say I should edit the question myself, but I think the OP might like/need to learn a little more $\TeX$, or maybe s/he really wants to use $z'$.

Comment: As rule, functions that involve  the complex conjugate of $z$ in an essential way are rarely differentiable in the complex sense, so I'd sense the CR equations are satisfied almost nowhere.  I'm rusty on Jacobians.  What did you actually get for the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$?

Comment: You can start by checking if $f$ has singularities. Then, $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2+\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ and $v(x,y)=\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$. Where is your problem with checking $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$, exactly?

Comment: @StefanSmith I'd rather write `$\bar z$`, saving a few keystrokes... $\bar z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have $f(z)$ right.  That is,
$$
f(x+iy) = x^2+y^2+ \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\implies\\
u(x,y)= x^2+y^2+ \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\\
v(x,y) = \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}
$$
Now, we find the partial derivatives to be
$$
u_x = 2x + \frac{4xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\
u_y = 2y - \frac{4x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\
v_x = \frac{2y^3-2x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\
v_y = \frac{2x^3-2xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$
Now, in order to find the points where $f$ satisfies the CR equations, find the solution to the simultaneous set of equations
$$
u_x(x,y) = v_y(x,y)\\
u_y(x,y) = -v_x(x,y)
$$
As Daniel's solution shows, the only points for which the above equality holds should be $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 12):

It is easier to solve this with the Wirtinger derivatives. For the given function we find

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}(z) = z - z\cdot \overline{z}^{-2},$$

hence

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}(z) = 0 \iff \overline{z}^2 = 1 \iff z = \pm 1,$$

and $f$ is complex differentiable in $z = \pm 1$ and nowhere else. In particular, it is not holomorphic in any point.

Answer (score 0):

$$z=x+iy\;,\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;\;,\;\;f(z)=z\overline z+\frac z{\overline z}=|z|^2+\frac{z^2}{|z|^2}=\underbrace{x^2+y^2+\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}}_{=u(x,y)}+\underbrace{\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}i}_{=iv(x,y)}=$$

$$=x^2+y^2+1-\frac{2y^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}i$$

Now

$$u_x=2x+\frac{4xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\;\;,\;\;v_y=\frac{2x(x^2+y^2)-2y\cdot2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{2x^3-2xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}...etc.$$

Now, you can already from the first set of differential equations see that there are some restrictions for $\;u_x=v_y\;$ . After this (if it is worthwhile), check when $\;u_y=-v_x\;$ ...